# Azure pipeline interface

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task

Is there a way to create a form like interface using Azure pipeline like the image shown below
So that every time I run the pipeline this form comes up ad let me choose the values for the fields defined

[image]

I know the question is very vague, but any help regarding this is greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi @anant. You could try the parameters and check if it could meet your requirements. If you have any update, feel free to let me know. If the answer could give you some help, you may consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a form like interface using Azure pipeline like the image shown below So that every time I run the pipeline this form comes up ad let me choose the values for the fields defined.

I am afraid that there is no such method could create a form to select the value.

But Azure Pipeline supports selecting values at runtime.

You could use `parameters` to create selection lists.

Here is an  example:

```
parameters:
- name: image
  displayName: Pool Image
  type: string
  default: ubuntu-latest
  values:
  - windows-latest
  - vs2017-win2016
  - ubuntu-latest
  - ubuntu-16.04
  - macOS-latest
  - macOS-10.14


- name: test
  displayName: Test for parameters
  type: string
  default: value1
  values:
  - value2
  - value3
  - value4
  - value5


trigger: none

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: build
  pool: 
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.image }}
  steps:
  - script: echo building $(Build.BuildNumber) with ${{ parameters.image }}
```

Then when you run the pipeline, you will see the selection lists.

[image: Run Pipeline]

By the way , when you quote parameters, you can use the following format:`${{ parameters.parametername }}`

Here is a doc about [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this not exactly what I was looking for but still it is very close, hence marking this as answer